# Why is there wrong number of arguments error when using the Thin gem v1.8.2 with Ruby 3.0.4?

Tags: ruby, thin, argument-error

When using Thin gem v1.8.2 with Ruby v3.0.4, there is an argument error for the wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1).  It appears that the Rack::Handler class was introduced in Thin v1.8.0.  The following shows the error that I am getting.

List of Gems:

- rake 13.0.6
- public_suffix 5.0.1
- bundler 2.4.12
- httpclient 2.8.3
- io-console 0.6.0
- json 2.6.3
- matrix 0.4.2
- racc 1.6.2
- nio4r 2.5.9
- rack 2.2.6.4
- ruby_expect 1.7.5
- rubyzip 1.3.0
- snmp 1.3.2
- uuidtools 2.2.0
- yard 0.9.34
- connection_pool 2.4.0
- faraday-net_http 3.0.2
- ruby2_keywords 0.0.5
- ffi 1.15.5
- tilt 2.1.0
- multi_json 1.15.0
- daemons 1.4.1
- eventmachine 1.2.7
- ruby-termios 1.1.0
- addressable 2.8.4
- reline 0.3.3
- nokogiri 1.14.3 (x86_64-linux)
- puma 5.6.5
- faraday 2.7.4
- mustermann 3.0.0
- faraday-retry 2.1.0
- ethon 0.16.0
- irb 1.6.4
- em-websocket 0.3.8
- debug 1.7.2
- rack-protection 3.0.6
- thin 1.8.2
- typhoeus 1.4.0
- sinatra 3.0.6
- sinatra-websocket 0.3.1
- faraday-typhoeus 1.0.0
- sinatra-contrib 3.0.6

Stack Trace:

```
2023-04-25 09:54:45 #<Thread:0x00007fbaaafbd328 /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/my-middleware-1.1.4/lib/middleware.rb:82 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
2023-04-25 09:54:45 /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/faraday-typhoeus-1.0.0/lib/faraday/adapter/typhoeus.rb:91:in `block in request': Couldn't connect to server (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus/request/callbacks.rb:146:in `block in execute_callbacks'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus/request/callbacks.rb:145:in `each'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus/request/callbacks.rb:145:in `execute_callbacks'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus/request/operations.rb:35:in `finish'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus/easy_factory.rb:164:in `block in set_callback'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/ethon-0.16.0/lib/ethon/easy/response_callbacks.rb:74:in `block in complete'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/ethon-0.16.0/lib/ethon/easy/response_callbacks.rb:74:in `each'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/ethon-0.16.0/lib/ethon/easy/response_callbacks.rb:74:in `complete'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/ethon-0.16.0/lib/ethon/easy/operations.rb:34:in `perform'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus/request/operations.rb:16:in `run'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus/request/cacheable.rb:18:in `run'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus/request/block_connection.rb:31:in `run'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus/request/stubbable.rb:25:in `run'
2023-04-25 09:54:45 2023/04/25 15:54:45.090 DEBUG: Middleware Logger is set up to record debugging messages
2023-04-25 09:54:45 2023/04/25 15:54:45.090 INFO: My Middleware creating a connection to CTS API at dev-base:5000
2023-04-25 09:54:45 2023/04/25 15:54:45.090 INFO: Main Middleware has finished initialization
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus/request/before.rb:26:in `run'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/faraday-typhoeus-1.0.0/lib/faraday/adapter/typhoeus.rb:48:in `perform_request'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/faraday-typhoeus-1.0.0/lib/faraday/adapter/typhoeus.rb:28:in `call'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/faraday-retry-2.1.0/lib/faraday/retry/middleware.rb:149:in `call'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/faraday-2.7.4/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:153:in `build_response'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/faraday-2.7.4/lib/faraday/connection.rb:444:in `run_request'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/faraday-2.7.4/lib/faraday/connection.rb:280:in `post'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/my-middleware-1.1.4/lib/cts_api.rb:102:in `block in handle_inside_pool'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/connection_pool-2.4.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:107:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/connection_pool-2.4.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:106:in `handle_interrupt'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/connection_pool-2.4.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:106:in `block in with'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/connection_pool-2.4.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:103:in `handle_interrupt'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/connection_pool-2.4.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:103:in `with'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/my-middleware-1.1.4/lib/cts_api.rb:101:in `handle_inside_pool'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/my-middleware-1.1.4/lib/cts_api.rb:67:in `handle_post'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/my-middleware-1.1.4/lib/utilities/cts_log_reader.rb:159:in `server_message_log_filename'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/my-middleware-1.1.4/lib/utilities/cts_log_reader.rb:52:in `start_populating_source'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/my-middleware-1.1.4/lib/utilities/cts_log_reader.rb:44:in `initialize'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/my-middleware-1.1.4/lib/middleware.rb:82:in `new'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/my-middleware-1.1.4/lib/middleware.rb:82:in `block in <class:MiddlewareApp>'
2023-04-25 09:54:45 bundler: failed to load command: main-middleware (/opt/app-root/src/bin/main-middleware)
2023-04-25 09:54:45 /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/thin-1.8.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:11:in `run': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/my-middleware-1.1.4/bin/main-middleware:33:in `<top (required)>'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/bin/main-middleware:25:in `load'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /opt/app-root/src/bin/main-middleware:25:in `<top (required)>'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/cli.rb:479:in `exec'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/cli.rb:31:in `dispatch'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/cli.rb:25:in `start'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.33/libexec/bundle:49:in `block in <top (required)>'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:103:in `with_friendly_errors'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.33/libexec/bundle:37:in `<top (required)>'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
2023-04-25 09:54:45     from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

After doing some more digging (given the clue in comments from Tom Lord and Todd Jacobs), I think I found the cause and solution.  The run method for Rack::Handler::Thin class accepts a keyword argument and could be called with a hash in Ruby 2.7.  But with the changes in Ruby 3.0, it appears that this is no longer allowed.

Before (ArgumentError):

```
myOptions = {
  Host: myHost,
  Port: myPort
}

Rack::Handler::Thin.run(MyApp, options=myOptions) <<-- no splat, hash arg
```

After (No Errors):

```
myOptions = {
  Host: myHost,
  Port: myPort
}

Rack::Handler::Thin.run(MyApp, **options=myOptions) <<-- dbl splat, hash arg
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full stack trace, not just a single line.

Comment: The problem seems to come from `/opt/app-root/src/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/my-middleware-1.1.4/bin/main-middleware:33`? The most likely cause is in relation to [separation of keyword and positional arguments in ruby 3.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/). For example, adding a double-splat operator (`**`) might fix the issue. But without seeing exactly what that code is, I cannot say for sure.

Comment: Please show the calling code around `main-middleware:33`. Without seeing that, we can't guess what's being passed.

Comment: The calling code was added above @TomLord (and Todd Jacobs).  This is what appears to be happening.  Let me know otherwise.  Thank you both.

Comment: Worth noting: This code would have *raised a deprecation warning* in ruby 2.7. It's always a good idea to fix all deprecations before performing a major version upgrade.